# Deleting rows in a table based on conditions in same table and another table.,not working as expected. using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, backend, dbeaver

I want to use the delete query to delete data from table T1 which contains historical data (eg. jan2020 - May 2022)and table T2 has data from (jan2022-july2022). i'm looking to delete all records of T2 from T1. I tried with the query:

```
where date between (select  min(test.`date`) from T2 test) 
and (select max(test.`date`) from T2 test )
```

The query executes, but it deletes all the (dec-2021,dec-2020 data) that we need. it deletes the wrong set of dates. what am I doing wrong here, pls help.

note - primary key not there for both the tables

thanks

Comment: Please provide the table-schema and a sample dataset for us to determine cause of the issue. eg: is `T2.date` a `DATETIME`  data-type or `VARCHAR`, etc? Assuming it is `DATETIME` as T2 only has `2022-01-01` to `2022-07-01`, according to the criteria any records prior to `2022-01-01` should not be deleted, so it appears the `T2.date` column is not of the `DATETIME` data-type or `SELECT min(t2.date)` is returning a date prior to `2022-01-01`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works, i tested with the following data, my guess is that there are data in your current table with date of dec-2021

```
CREATE TABLE HistoricData
(
    some_data VARCHAR(100),
    date datetime
)

INSERT INTO HistoricData (some_data, date) VALUES 
('historic data', '2020-01-01'),
('historic data', '2020-02-01'),
('historic data', '2021-03-01'),
('historic data', '2022-02-01'),
('historic data', '2022-05-01')

CREATE TABLE CurrentData
(
    some_data VARCHAR(100),
    date datetime
)

INSERT INTO CurrentData (some_data, date) VALUES 
('current data', '2022-01-01'),
('current data', '2022-02-01'),
('current data', '2022-03-01'),
('current data', '2022-04-01'),
('current data', '2022-05-01')

DELETE FROM HistoricData
where date between (select  min(`date`) from CurrentData) 
and (select max(`date`) from CurrentData )
```